# Group of 8 people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Question:
A group of 8 people consists of 4 men and 4 women.

(i) Find the number of ways to form a committee of 2 women and 1 man.

(ii) Find the number of ways to arrange the 8 people in a row if all the women cannot be
together.

Jai and Kai belong to the group of 8 people. During a photo-taking session, 8 chairs are
arranged into 2 rows with 4 chairs in each row.

(iii) Find the number of ways to arrange the 8 people on the 8 chairs, given that Jai and
Kai must be in the centre of the front row.

My answers:

(i)  $\binom{4}{2} \cdot$ $\binom{4}{1} = 24$

(ii)  8! - (5*4!*4!) = 37 440

(iii) 2! * 6! = 1440

Are all my answers correct? If not, what is incorrect? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Yes they are correct

Answer (score 1):

Indeed.

(*i*) $\checkmark~ \binom 42\binom 41$ counts selections of 2 from 4 women and 1 from 4 men.

(*ii*)  $\checkmark~8!-5!~4!$ counts arrangements of 8 people *excluding* arrangements that place the 4 women in a block.

(*iii*) $\checkmark~2!~6!$ counts arrangements of the particular two in the specified two seats times arrangements of the other six in theirs.